# difference between * function() and function()

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers

everyone, 
one thing is made my mind busy is pointers for function
what is the difference between these two codes?

```
#include<iostream>

class test
{
    private:
        // some data members

    public:
        void *print() **OR** void Print()
        {
            // print something
        }

}
```

why we have the pointer function? 
what's the difference between them?

BEST REGARDS

Comment: void *print() returns void pointer (void * ) while void Print() returns nothing

Comment: Better read: It's `void` or `void*` not `print()` or `*print()`. The asterix belongs to the return type of the function. You can confirm this by compiling the code. You should get a warning like `no return statement in function returning non-void` with the "asterix-version ".

Comment: I'm sure there's a question about this already - you are asking about the difference between returning a void pointer or not returning anything. In other words `*` belongs to  the `void`, not the function `Print`.

Comment: @Shadow that's "asterisk", Asterix is the Gaulish warrior ;)

Answer (score 0):

the answer is:

when you wanna return a pointer you have two ways to do that

1: in this way you don't need * to return the value of your pointer

```
int* (int* a , int* b)
{
    if(*a < *b)
       return a;
}
```

2: in this way you need to use * to return the value of your pointer

```
int (int* a , int* b)
    {
        if(*a < *b)
           return *a;
    }
```